# Given Joint density compute the probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ as

$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}y^2e^{-x}, 0<y<x<\infty$

Then, it is required to compute $P(Y<1|X = 3)$.

By the conditional probability formula:

$P(Y<1|X = 3) = \frac{P(Y<1,X = 3)}{P(X = 3)}$

Since, X is a continuous distribution, the denominator should just be 0 and hence the probability does not exist here but the textbook is giving the answer as $\frac{1}{27}$. How is this possible? I don't need this answer, I realise how they might have derived this. But i need an explanation as to why they did not consider this denominator to be zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with continuous random variables $(X,Y)$  with joint density $f(x,y)$ you can compute the conditional density of $Y$ using the analog of the conditional probability formula applied to densities:

$$
f(y \mid x) = \frac{f(x,y)}{f(x)}
$$

where $f(x)$ is the marginal density of $X$ :
$$
f(x) = \int f(x,y) dy
$$
The function $f(y \mid x)$ is the density of the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$.

Then the probability $\mathbb P(Y < 1 \mid X = 3)$ can be computed as:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^1 f(y \mid 3) dy
$$

When $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}y^2e^{-x}I_{0<y<x<\infty}$, a quick integration shows that $f(x) = \frac{1}{6}x^3 e^{-x}I_{x>0}$ and thus

$$
f(y \mid x) = \frac{3y^2}{x^3} I_{0 \leq y \leq x}
$$

from which we can compute $\mathbb P( Y < 1 \mid X=3)$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P( Y < 1 \mid X = 3) &= \int_0^1 \frac{3y^2}{27}dy \\
&= \frac{1}{27}
\end{align*}